# CSS Parallax image issues with image cutting off

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, parallax

Having issues on this site (http://rvwinvesting.com/2016/) where I have two parallax images.One is a seamless background in the middle and the other is a photo of a series of offices buildings near the footer on the bottom of the page. That's the issue. When you scroll up, the too and bottom of the page appears so it looks odd instead of one scrolling image. Is there some way I can clear this up? The image is over 1200px in height  and the div is only 600px and I've tried smaller div sizes as well and no matter what, that seam appears. Here's my CSS for that div:

```
#building {
    background: url(http://rvwinvesting.com/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/rvw-building.jpg) 50% 0 fixed;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover!important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    -o-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
 }
```

Tried100%100% for background-size but that just stretches the photo. No good.

Comment: Can you explain the problem more clearly. I can't understand what is wrong or what you are trying to do. If the footer and the rest of the page are looking odd the decrease the height of #building and add a translucent black div in front of it or decrease the brightness of the picture using a photo editor.

Comment: Sure. Basically, as the scroll is happening, the photo of the buildings move up but you can see the seam between the top and bottom of the photo. So basically the photo (I guess) starts midway at the top and goes to midway once it reaches the bottom. What should happens is the photo starts at the top and moves to the bottom. You never see the seam.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally got it to work. A padding-top setting seemed to make all the difference. Here's the new code:

```
#building {
    background: url(http://rvwinvesting.com/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/rvw-building.jpg) 50% 0 fixed;
    background-position: top center !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding-top: 250px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
 }
```

Comment: For me it was doing "background-position: top center;" instead of "background-position: top;". Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

The top and bottom part of the image are croped out as the #building is wider than the image. You can either make the div longer or find a wider image.

Comment: But should you use an image that is twice the height of the actual div? So if the div is 500px in height....shouldn't the image then be 1000px in height?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your problem clearly but if you are talking about the repeating issue of building at the bottom, here is my suggestion:

1. You don't have to use `!important` after `background-size` (just clearing your code a bit)
2. add `no-repeat` on background to avoid multiple building background.
3. only start the parallax of building background when it's on viewport or just before the viewport. In your case when `#building` reach to the bottom of the screen, start parallax effect.

Hope it will help.

---

## Updated on March 22, 2016

I downloaded this theme (BootstrapParallax) and played around it, please do the following things in-order to start your parallax only when it appear:

**add new "data" attributes to your desired `div/section`: `data-start-at="bottom"`
so your `div/section` will be something like:

```
<section id="building" data-speed="4" data-type="background" data-start-at="bottom">
```

after that, find this .js file inside your theme folder (path: js/strap-extras.js) and replace with following code:

```
// Placeholder
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     // cache the window object
     jQuerywindow = jQuery(window);

     jQuery('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
       // declare the variable to affect the defined data-type
       var jQueryscroll = jQuery(this),
          startAt = jQueryscroll.data('start-at'),
          yPos, coords, thisOffset;

        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          // HTML5 proves useful for helping with creating JS functions!
          // also, negative value because we're scrolling upwards    

          if(!startAt) {

             yPos = -(jQuerywindow.scrollTop() / jQueryscroll.data('speed'));

            // background position
            coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

          } else {
            thisOffset = jQueryscroll.offset();
            thisTop = thisOffset.top;

            //console.log(thisTop - jQuerywindow.outerHeight(), ' wondow: ', jQuerywindow.scrollTop());

            if( (thisTop - jQuerywindow.outerHeight()) < jQuerywindow.scrollTop() ) {

               yPos = -(jQuerywindow.scrollTop() / jQueryscroll.data('speed'));
              // background position
              coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            }

          }

          // move the background
          jQueryscroll.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });   
        }); // end window scroll
     });  // end section function
  }); // close out script

  document.createElement("section");
```

*PS: js can be write in more clear and efficient way, this is just an example.*

And, please clear your css, you don't need `!important` everywhere.

Your clean css can be this:

```
#building {
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/rvw-building.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

you may need to adjust a bit, but hope it will solve your problems.

Otherwise, you have to learn how to write js/css :)

enjoy!

--
Jimba

Comment: Adding no-repeat just brings a lot of white into the div. Not good.

Comment: @AdamBell look at my suggestion in #3. You have to start parallax effect for #building div only when that div hit the bottom of screen.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that. I tried 'top' and 0px but that didn't work.

Comment: @AdamBell It's still showing repeated images on mobile. Adding padding will not work for all screen sizes. It'll be better if you try to understand how parallax is working and follow the suggestion by Jimba Tamang. Starting parallax only when needed will also improve scrolling performance.